# Java: ExecutorService with Callables: Reuse the same Pool in a loop? Shutdown necessary?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, executorservice, callable

I got a loop `{Loop-1}`, where I start Threads. The class which contains the `{Loop-1}` implements Daemon and Runnable.
In the `{Loop-1}` the thread, which is started, calls a method `coordinate()` of a class `Coordinate.java` where I use the ExecutorService.

When the object of `Coordinate.java` is created (this happens once BEFORE `{Loop-1}`), I instantiate a ExecutorService 
`pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);`

In `coordinate()` I create two Objects of a class which implements Callable and I start them then and store the result in a List of Future results.
`callableResults = pool.invokeAll(threads);`

After, I try to get the results in a loop with `result = future.get();`

Then, I return to `{Loop-1}` and the whole process starts again (call `coordinate()`, `invokeAll()`, `future.get()`

Now Ive got the following question: 
1. Do I need to shutdown the pool of ExecutorService after I got the results in `coordinate()`?
2. Do I need to recreate the pool everytime my `{Loop-1}` calls `coordinate()`?

Thanks for answers! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shutdown the executorService once you're done processing **all** your tasks.
The submission of tasks can be in multiple cycles.

Once you call `executorService.shutDown()`, you can wait until all tasks are completed after calling shutDown() using `executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Alternatively, you can do: `while (!executorService.isTerminated()) { }`

Comment: This is ugly: `while (!executorService.isTerminated()) { }`. It would make a core go crazy on 100% while there are unfinished tasks! `awaitTermination` is way better.

Answer (score 2):

No you do not. The threads in the fixed thread pool can be used until you call `shutdown` on it. So, you can simply resubmit new tasks to be executed and fetch their results, exactly as you did in the first go-round.